# Using the LRT statistic to test $H_0$ vs $H_1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

Let ${Y_1,...,Y_n}$ be independent random variables and $Y_i$~$N(\beta x_i, 1)$ where $x_1,...,x_n$ are fixed known constants, and $\beta$ is an unknown parameter.

I'm looking to find the p-value or rejection region for  the test

$$H_0: \beta=0 \quad \text{vs} \quad H_1:\beta\ne0$$

The Likelihood Ratio Test statistic $\Lambda$ is

$$e^{-1/2\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}\right)^2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$$

I have already asked a similar question with $H_1: \beta>0$ here: [Uniformly Most Powerful test for normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283891/uniformly-most-powerful-test-for-normal-distribution).

After setting $\Lambda < k$ I'm left with $\sum x_iy_i$ after removing constants to the right, which is the same as my previous question. How will finding the p-value or rejection region for this test differ?

Comment: I haven't tried this problem myself, but would like to remark that it is possible for the LRT to be the same as the UMP test.

Comment: $x_iy_i\sim N(\beta x_i^2,x_i^2)$, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i \sim N(\beta \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)$. Under $H_0$, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i \sim N(0, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)$.

Comment: @NCh this is the exact same distribution of the l.h.s. as in my previous question. Will the rejection region, p-value, or steps  not differ in any way even though this test is 2-sided ($\beta \ne 0$ except $\beta>0$) ?

Comment: @NCh I'm thinking the answer to my question will be intuitive and somewhat obvious, but I just want to make sure. Thank you.

Comment: Try to solve inequality $\Lambda<k$ w.r.t. $\sum x_iy_i$ or $\frac{\sum x_iy_i}{\sqrt{\sum x_i^2}}$ and you can see the answer by your own.

Comment: @NCh I dont understand how solving this inquality will answer my question. I did solve it but from what I know its only the left side of the inequality and the direction of it that will will be used to find the rejection region. So the right side shouldn't matter. From the examples I've seen the it seems the rejection region should be the same. Though since this test is two sided I'm thinking the rejection region be $$
z_{1-\alpha/2}\cdot\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}\geq\sum_{i=1}^n y_ix_i \geq z_{1-\alpha/2}\cdot\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}.
$$

Comment: Please show your solution of the inequality $$e^{-T^2/2} < k$$ w.r.t. $T=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i x_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}}$.

Comment: @NCh Here is my solution $$\sqrt{-2*\text{log}(k)}<T<-\sqrt{-2*\text{log}(k)}$$ I'm currently trying to figure out how to use this to get the rejection region, so I'll return later with my findings. I also know that $$T~N(0,\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x^2)$$

Comment: @NCh Sorry I made another mistake above, now I'm getting T~N(0,1), I'm just a little frustrated since I've spent so much time on this question so I apologize for these seemingly careless mistakes.

Comment: You solve inequality incorrect. Do you see minus in power of exponent?

Comment: Yes I see the minus sign. To double check my work I used wolfram alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+e%5E(-T%5E2%2F2)%3Ck+for+T

Comment: How do you solve the inequality $-x^2<1$? You wrote that the solution is $1<x<-1$. What does it mean? Wolframalpha solves your inequality correct.

Comment: @NCh Thank you for all your help. I'm now moving on from this question.